# Python SKLearn with signal features

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, feature-extraction

***Problem presentation***

I have a dataset of size (19, 1000, 100), with :

```
- 100 SAMPLES
- 19 channels / samples of length 1000 (2 s at 500 Hz)
```

The dataset is label, with a vector of length 100.

I would like to use a learning algorithm, and of course, to get the best fitting possible. In order to do that, I split my dataset into a training set and a test set. Current code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Library importation
import os
import numpy as np
from scipy import io as sio
from scipy import signal
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Functions

def filter(x, n, fs, fc1, fc2):
    b, a = signal.butter(n, [fc1/(fs/2), fc2/(fs/2)], 'bandpass')
    y = signal.filtfilt(b, a, x)
    return y

def haming(x, L):
    # Symetric L-points hamming window
    window = signal.hamming(L)
    y = x * window.T                            # Element wise multiplication
    return y

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Script

s_EEG = "{}/{}".format(EEG_path, EEG[4])
data = sio.loadmat(s_EEG)['s_EEG']['data'][0][0].astype(float)     # data[i, j ,k]
labels = sio.loadmat(s_EEG)['s_EEG']['labels'][0][0][0]            # labels[k]
fs = sio.loadmat(s_EEG)['s_EEG']['sampling_rate'][0][0][0][0]      # 500 Hz
size = data.shape                                                  # (i,j,k)

for i in range(size[0]):
    for k in range(size[2]):
        data[i,:,k] = haming(filter(data[i,:,k], 10, fs, 1, 45), size[1])

data = data.reshape(size[0] * size[1], size[2]).T

# X signal / Y label
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(data, list(labels), test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print (clf.score(X_test, Y_test))
```

Each sample is filtered (bandpass between 1 Hz and 45 Hz).
A hamming window is applied on each sample.

The data is then reshaped in the form 100 * 19 000, by placing samples one after another.

***Questions***

1. Is the method correct ?
2. By placing samples one after another, doesn't it create problems ?
3. How could I use a lot of features for the classification ?
   For instance, spectrum analysis, synchronisation method between channels, mean, variance... Would it be ok to extract a "feature signal" for every sample, and then to places them one after another, i.e, the input of the svc would be a matrix of size 100 * A LOT ? Is there a way to keep the signal in the form:

> (samples * (channel 1, channel 2, ... channel 19, feature 1, feature
>   2, ...))

Or even better :

> (samples * ((channel 1, channel 2, ... channel 19), (feature 1 for
>   channel 1, feature 1 for channel 2, ...), (feature 2 for chan 1,
>   feature 2 for chan 2, ...)))

Since I don't know which feature could be intersting in my signal (EEG data...), I need to test a lot of different features and to keep the best one.

Thanks for the help !

P.S: Any optimisation of the code, in term of speed, memory, simplicity would be great :)